# Swift - How to use UIGraphics blend mode?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, uigraphicscontext

I would like to develop a kind of progress bar animation for AppleWatch. 
I decided to do it all with the **UIGraphicContext**.

Since I'm a complete beginner I don't really understand how I can apply some kind of "*globalCompositeOperation*" to my context.

To illustrate my idea better here are some pictures:

[image: Image #1]

[image: Image #2]

[image: Image #3]

---

This is my source code so far:

```
let size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 100)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

context.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
context.fill(CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width * 0.5, height: size.height))
context.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.destinationOver)

let count = 5;
let padding = (size.width / CGFloat(count)) * 0.5
for i in 0...count {
    let offsetX = size.width * (CGFloat(i) / CGFloat(count))
    let rect = CGRect(x: offsetX + padding/2, y: 0, width: padding, height: size.height)
    context.setFillColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
    context.fill(rect)
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

---

I guess this is kind of the wrong approach because the result is more like this:

[image: Image #4]

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess this is not a valid Watchkit solution: The guy from the post is talking about stacking multiple views - this is no option for WK. Thanks anyways. @matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @matt's answer using `.sourceAtop` I found a working solution for WatchKit:

```
let size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 100)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
let count = 5;
let padding = (size.width / CGFloat(count)) * 0.5
for i in 0...count {
    let offsetX = size.width * (CGFloat(i) / CGFloat(count))
    let rect = CGRect(x: offsetX + padding/2, y: 0, width: padding, height: size.height)
    context.setFillColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
    context.fill(rect)
}

context.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
context.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.sourceAtop)
context.fill(CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width * 0.5, height: size.height))

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Answer (score 2):

You want `.sourceAtop`. Here's a demonstration:

```
    let green = UIImage(named:"green.png")! // your original 5 green rects
    let sz = green.size
    let red = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:sz).image {
        ctx in
        UIColor.red.setFill()
        // width value determines how much we will fill
        ctx.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sz.width/2, height: sz.height))
    }
    let result = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:sz).image {
        ctx in
        green.draw(at: .zero)
        red.draw(at: .zero, blendMode: .sourceAtop, alpha: 1)
    }
```

[image]

Just vary the value at `width: sz.width/2` for different "thermometer" amounts.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. Looks like a working solution for iOS but unfortunately UIGraphicsImageRenderer is not available on watchOS.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that! But it shows you that this is the right blend mode, which is what you really needed to know.